# Confused how to find cycles in undirected graph with dead ends

Tags: c#, graph-theory

I have been thinking about how to find a cycle in my graph data but i am a bit lost in how i keep track of where i am travelling on the graph and how to back track when i find a dead end.

Here is a visual example:

[image]

I can easily find the loop here by following the path until i get back to 0 - the problem is at node 3, i have to check node 4 and 5.

It's obvious how ever 4->5 will be a dead end and won't be part of the cycle, but how do you then write code to back track to node 3 to continue on to 6?

Comment: How can I answer a c# question that doesn't contain any code? Since your question is abstract, adding the language probably triggered the closure.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman it was a graph theory question, i only put C# because if some one replied "oh you can use this python library" it would not be very useful in my case as i only do C#. But pseudo code is equally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of depth-first-search, you can store the nodes in a "visited" set

As you go-to new nodes, add to the set after checking `visited.Contains()`. If true, you have a cycle (came back to the same node more than once)

So, logically, say you started at 3 (or came to it), and edges are picked at random since they are not directed

```
(program-start) visited = {}

at = 3, visited={3}
at = 4, visited={3, 4}
at = 5, visited={3, 4, 5}
```

Here, you have to pick the only edge from 5 to traverse, sending you back to 4, and checking your set, its already there...

Comment: I think i understand, sorta lol. Since i ran out of edges at 5 because they have all been visited i have to pop a node from the visited stack which will send me back to the previous node. And keep going until i reach a node, in this case 3 that has more segments to explore...

Comment: IMHO keep a stack for the search queue, don't push the visited nodes, push every link except the one you arrived on.

Comment: What do you mean a stack of the search queue ? 

My interpretation of it so far was keep a stack of visited nodes so i can go backwards the way i came since its FILO and also keep a hash set of edges i've traversed to check if i have already been down a particular path. Haven't ran the test yet as i'm still writing it but will step through with debugger to see if my logic failed.

Comment: Ok just ran it, it works :) I understand it now was much simpler than my initial expectations.